# Appending to a dropdown list in Jade using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I'm trying to add entries to a dropdown list which I have defined in my .jade file as below.

```
extends layout

block content
    script(src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='/javascripts/addsystem.js')
    h1= title
    p Testing


    select#allSystems
```

And my Ajax method looks like the following:

```
var select = $('#allSystems');
console.log("Runing script")


$.ajax({
  url: '/submit/getAllSystems',
  dataType:'JSON',
  success:function(data){

    $.each(test.system, function(key, val) {
        select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>'); 
    })
  }
});
```

The Ajax script is located the JS file which is included in the Jade file. (Jquery is also included in the Jade file).

Everything seems to be working fine, except for the append. I.e. the console logs show good data all the way and when printing the select object in the Ajax script the browser recognizes it as a HTML element.

When printing the running "console.log(select);", Firefox console shows the following:

```
Object { context: HTMLDocument → submit, selector: "#allSystems" }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post either your Jade file or your rendered HTML as well?

Comment: Are you running `$('#allSystems')` before the DOM is ready?

Comment: Tha'ts what I was just about to add to my answer.

Comment: Mike and Paul. I have no idea. How do I check? I don't even know if I'm readying the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jade is a templating language that has to be compiled and executed with the data in order to render HTML.  JQuery will not automatically do that for you, which is why your commented-out attempt at `select.append` failed.

Building the HTML yourself works (though it makes some ugly code and I still dislike string concatenations). However, when you did that you changed to `.appendTo`, which is going to try and take your `select` object and append it to the `option`, which I don't think is what you want.

give this a shot:

```
select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
```

If that doesn't work, then there's something up with your selector that gets you the `select` variable.

*** EDIT ***
I notice in your Jade that you are loading your scripts before the rest of the DOM.  IF the contents of addsystem.js are as you describe, then you're fetching the data and trying to append it to a DOM node that doesn't exist yet.  Try wrapping it like so:

```
$(function(){ /** your code **/ })
```

Which is a shorthands to jQuery's methods for doing stuff after the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I included a temporary version of the code where I was just testing random things since what I thought was right didn't work. I've edited my post and the current version seems to match what you are suggesting, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I will also include some info regarding the selector, since that might be the problem as you suggested. I'll edit the question soon.

Comment: No, what you're showing looks fine.  Assuming from your comment that the test object has a `system` property, which is a collection of objects then the loop should work.  What are you seeing in the DOM after the ajax call executes? Are you getting malformed option tags, blank tags, nothing? Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors, and the options tags are unchanged i.e. the static html is in its original version.

Comment: In your console, try just using the syntax you're trying.  So for example, type `$('#allSystems').append('<option id="2323234234243">Test Option</option>')` and hit enter, and observe if that updates your DOM or not.  If not, then #allSystems isn't the right ID.  if so, then the odds are good that your data structure isn't in line with how you expect it to be, and you haven't noticed.

Comment: I just moved the script includes to the bottom of block content as you suggested in the edit of your answer. I was confused about the DOM stuff yesterday, had no idea what it was since I'm new to web programming. Looking at it with fresh eyes today, however, it all made sense. Thanks a lot!